# How to run a localhost website in Android phone which is run on laptop

Tags: html, css, testing, visual-web-developer, liveserver

I recently started developing a Website. However, I am having trouble running it on localhost. When I type http://localhost in my web browser.
I recently started developing a Website. However, I am having trouble running it on localhost. When I type http://localhost in my web browser.
css

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Run localhost on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps:
Step 1: open CMD and write `ipconfig`

Step 2: Find `ipv4 address` which is look like  `IPv4 Address : 192.168.x.x`

Step 3: write the address into your mobile phone and in the last add `:PORT` PORT= Write the PORT number on which your website is running it is shown in `browser url` or `live server` extension in `vscode`

url: `http://192.168.x.x:PORT`

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost is the machine the code is running on, it acts like a server, but locally. If you want to access the website on your mobile phone, you need to find your computer's IP Address. you can get this by opening a command prompt and typing in `ipconfig` and checking for the IPv4 address, there might be two, try either of them. Then make sure your phone and computer are connected to the same network (e.g like let the computer and phone be connected to the same WiFi. Make sure the wifi is not private though) you can then use this IP on your phone, followed by the port number for example `192.158.1.38:4000` where `4000` is the port number.

And from you tag of `css`, I am guessing you want to test responsive code, I can advice you check your browser's dev tools by right clicking on anywhere on the browser window and clicking inspect, from here, you can toggle between mobile and desktop view, or even choose different mobile devices to see what your website will look like on those devices

let me know if you need any more assistance. Hope this was helpful :)